# Generating a random key in AES using aes python package

Tags: python, encryption, key, aes, generator

I'm making a program that encrypts a text with aes package. I generated a random key using secrets.token_bytes(16) and i tried secrets.token_hex(16) too.

But every time i run a code i get an error that says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'bytes' and 'int'` and this part of aes package is shown

```
 def __toarray(self, ints):
        if type(ints) == list and len(ints) == 16:
            return ints
        arr = [((ints >> (8 * (15 - i))) & 0xFF) for i in range(16)]
```

I don't know how can i fix this. Is there any way to generate an random key?

This is how my code looks like:

```
import secrets
import aes

text = "ala ma kota a marysia ma rysia"

key = secrets.token_bytes(16)
key_list = list(key)
key_hex = []
for i in range(len(key_list)):
    key_hex.append(hex(key_list[i])


def padding_and_hex(txt):
    txt_hex = []
    txt_dec = list(txt)
    if len(txt_dec) % 16 != 0:
        for i in range(16 - len(txt_dec) % 16):
            txt_dec.append(0)
        for i in range(len(txt_dec)):
            txt_hex.append(hex(txt_dec[i]))
    return txt_hex


text_to_encrypt = padding_and_hex(text)
how_many_times = int(len(text_to_encrypt)//16)

for i in range(how_many_times):
    cipher = aes.aes(key)
    cipher.encrypt(text_to_encrypt[i:i+16])
    i += 16
```

Comment: Could you please specify the library you are using for AES? Also, the code you posted is broken: There is a closing bracket missing in the line with `key_hex.append(...)`. In `padding_and_hex`, the hex encoding is only applied to the whole text when its length is not divisible by 16. Is this wanted? It would seem to me the hex encoding should be applied in either case. Also, the function fails because you are appending ints to a char list. You could fix this by appending `'\0'` instead. Please fix these issues to allow us to reproduce the actual error you were asking about.